# Which format the data should be in to successfully insert it to a table in Netezza DB using RJDBC

Tags: sql, r, rjdbc

I'm trying to insert new rows to an empty table in the DB using `dbSendUpdate()` from RJDBC package. 
The fields in the table are as such:

- integer(10)
- varchar(255)
- bigint(19)
- smallint(5)
- double(15)

The columns in the data.frame are:

- character
- numeric
- int

The way I'm doing it, I'm trying to:

- insert numeric into double(15),
- character into varchar(255)
- int into smallint(5)
- numeric into bigint(19)
- integers to integer(10)

I'm exporting the data.frame to csv and try to load it to the DB.
Could someone explain the correspondence between R and SQL column types, so they could be inserted to the DB?

The error I'm getting is `External table count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit`, although R doesn't give me the info about which column/row causes the problem. I'm not very good with SQL, so I'm not sure where to dig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I had character columns with commas in them. That messed the csv file, as comma symbol was a delimiter, so it was no longer valid. After this was fixed, I was able to upload the data without problems. So I guess my scheme of corresponding types was ok after all